# Is there any way to merge two list of dictionaries in python without having duplicates

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I want to merge these two lists of dictionaries into one in python -

#### Input

```
arr1 = [
{ "field": 'nickname', "direction": 'ASC' },
{ "field": 'email', "direction": 'ASC' },
{ "field": 'name', "direction": 'ASC' },
{ "field": 'first_name', "direction": 'ASC' }
]

arr2 = [
{ "field" : "nickname", "direction" : "DESC"},
{ "field" : "email", "direction" : "DESC"},
{ "field" : "last_name", "direction" : "DESC"}
]
```

and need the output -

#### Output

```
[
    { field: "nickname",   direction: "DESC"},
    { field: "email",      direction: "DESC"},
    { field: "last_name",  direction: "DESC"},
    { field: "name",       direction: "ASC" },
    { field: "first_name", direction: "ASC" }
]
```

My Solution -

```
arr1 = [
{ "field": 'nickname', "direction": 'ASC' },
{ "field": 'email', "direction": 'ASC' },
{ "field": 'name', "direction": 'ASC' },
{ "field": 'first_name', "direction": 'ASC' }
]

arr2 = [
{ "field" : "nickname", "direction" : "DESC"},
{ "field" : "email", "direction" : "DESC"},
{ "field" : "last_name", "direction" : "DESC"}
]

arr4 = arr2;
arr3 = []

for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
    for j in range(0, len(arr2)):
        flag = 0
        if(arr1[i]['field'] == arr2[j]['field']):
            arr3.append(arr2[j])
            arr4.remove(arr2[j])
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 0 :
        arr3.append(arr1[i])

arr3 += arr4
print(arr3)
```

I tried several ways but need to do it in O(n) complexity and without modifying arr2. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = {}
for d in arr1 + arr2:
    out[d["field"]] = d["direction"]

out = [{"field": k, "direction": v} for k, v in out.items()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"field": "nickname", "direction": "DESC"},
    {"field": "email", "direction": "DESC"},
    {"field": "name", "direction": "ASC"},
    {"field": "first_name", "direction": "ASC"},
    {"field": "last_name", "direction": "DESC"},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner would be going for pandas:

`df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(arr1).append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(arr2)).drop_duplicates('field', keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)`

and the result is:

```
        field direction
0        name       ASC
1  first_name       ASC
2    nickname      DESC
3       email      DESC
4   last_name      DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm should be simple:

1. Create a new Map for the result
2. Decide which key/value pairs from each input Map (or list of Maps) shall take priority in case of collisions (duplicate keys mapping to different values)
3. Write your iteration construct on the input map, considering the order and priority.

Q: Should the keys of the maps appearing earlier in the list of maps retain their value? Or should the keys of the maps appearing later in the list of maps?